# Help with hauppauge wintv-hvr-2250 on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I've been following the instructions on this website: http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-2200

I'm by no means an expert and I'm stuck on the section titled "Making It Work". where it says:

To get the card working you'll have to

```
apply the this patch
download v4l-saa7164-1.0.2-3.fw and copy it to /lib/modules
```

I have no clue how to apply the patch and I'm looking for some help. Thank you.

Comment: Ubuntu may recognize your card. Have you tried using it on VLC. It can open TV tuner cards.

Comment: ubuntu recognizes the card but vlc does not open it.

Answer (score 3):

I recently purchased the same card knowing nothing about tv-tuner cards and linux.
I had a rough time setting it up and at one point I almost returned the card thinking it was a bad buy.

I'm glad I didn't because the card works nicely with my setup.

Here's what I did

I copied these files

```
NXP7164-2010-03-10.1.fw
v4l-saa7164-1.0.2-3.fw
v4l-saa7164-1.0.3-3.fw
```

to `/lib/firmware`

you can get them from here  http://www.steventoth.net/linux/hvr22xx/firmwares/

just look through the folders and you'll find them.

reboot and they should load.

you can check with `dmesg | grep saa7164`

this is my output

---

```
[   23.126026] saa7164 driver loaded
[   23.126116] saa7164 0000:05:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   23.128214] CORE saa7164[0]: subsystem: 0070:8851, board: Hauppauge WinTV-HVR2250 [card=7,autodetected]
[   23.128224] saa7164[0]/0: found at 0000:05:00.0, rev: 129, irq: 16, latency: 0, mmio: 0xfd800000
[   23.128234] saa7164 0000:05:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   23.305001] saa7164_downloadfirmware() no first image
[   23.305024] saa7164_downloadfirmware() Waiting for firmware upload (NXP7164-2010-03-10.1.fw)
[   24.346108] saa7164_downloadfirmware() firmware read 4019072 bytes.
[   24.346113] saa7164_downloadfirmware() firmware loaded.
[   24.346129] saa7164_downloadfirmware() SecBootLoader.FileSize = 4019072
[   24.346136] saa7164_downloadfirmware() FirmwareSize = 0x1fd6
[   24.346139] saa7164_downloadfirmware() BSLSize = 0x0
[   24.346142] saa7164_downloadfirmware() Reserved = 0x0
[   24.346145] saa7164_downloadfirmware() Version = 0x1661c00
[   31.208034] saa7164_downloadimage() Image downloaded, booting...
[   31.312020] saa7164_downloadimage() Image booted successfully.
[   33.436032] saa7164_downloadimage() Image downloaded, booting...
[   35.308041] saa7164_downloadimage() Image booted successfully.
[   35.352417] saa7164[0]: Hauppauge eeprom: model=88061
[   35.961461] DVB: registering new adapter (saa7164)
[   38.890487] DVB: registering new adapter (saa7164)
[   38.891328] saa7164[0]: registered device video0 [mpeg]
[   39.122255] saa7164[0]: registered device video1 [mpeg]
[   39.332681] saa7164[0]: registered device vbi0 [vbi]
[   39.332747] saa7164[0]: registered device vbi1 [vbi]
```

---

I've used both the analog and digital parts of the card but at the moment I'm only using the analog side because my cable provider only gives me what I'm currently paying for via analog.

I'm sure you already know this but

ivtv-utils and vlc are great tools for testing and debugging

Comment: This worked great for me. Simply `cd /lib/firmware` and `sudo wget <URL>` the files!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you don't need the patch.

The Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-2500 needs several files in order to be detected.  These are the files contained in my `/lib/firmware/3.8.0-27-generic` directory: `dvb-fe-tda10048-1.0.fw`, `NXP7164-2010-03-10.1.fw`, `v4l-saa7164-1.0.2.fw`, `v4l-saa7164-1.0.3.fw`, `v4l-saa7164-1.0.3-3.fw`.  If you obtained the files from http://onwww.steventoth.net, as instructed on the web page at http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-2200, and ran the script:

```
sh extract.sh
```

the necessary files should be located in your home directory. All you need to do is copy them by navigating to your home directory in a terminal and using the cp command:

```
sudo cp *fw /lib/firmware/3.8.0-27-generic  [enter your password when prompted].
```

This will copy all files with the `.fw` suffix to the firmware sub-directory.  Then reboot.

To see that that your card is recognized, open a terminal and enter:

```
dmesg | grep 7164
```

You should see something like:

```
[    0.253798] pci 0000:02:00.0: [1131:7164] type 00 class 0x048000  
[   15.412176] saa7164 driver loaded  
[   15.412653] CORE saa7164[0]: subsystem: 0070:8851, board: Hauppauge WinTV-HVR2250 [card=7,autodetected]  
[   15.412658] saa7164[0]/0: found at 0000:02:00.0, rev: 129, irq: 16, latency:
0, mmio: 0xfe400000  
[   15.648146] saa7164_downloadfirmware() no first image  
[   15.648213] saa7164_downloadfirmware() Waiting for firmware upload 
(NXP7164-2010-03-10.1.fw)  
[   17.518041] saa7164_downloadfirmware() firmware read 4019072 bytes.  
[   17.518044] saa7164_downloadfirmware() firmware loaded.  
[   17.518077] saa7164_downloadfirmware() SecBootLoader.FileSize = 4019072  
[   17.518082] saa7164_downloadfirmware() FirmwareSize = 0x1fd6  
[   17.518083] saa7164_downloadfirmware() BSLSize = 0x0  
[   17.518084] saa7164_downloadfirmware() Reserved = 0x0  
[   17.518085] saa7164_downloadfirmware() Version = 0x1661c00  
[   24.396922] saa7164_downloadimage() Image downloaded, booting...  
[   24.501486] saa7164_downloadimage() Image booted successfully.  
[   27.220221] saa7164_downloadimage() Image downloaded, booting...  
[   29.086382] saa7164_downloadimage() Image booted successfully.  
[   29.136008] tveeprom 6-0000: audio processor is SAA7164 (idx 43)  
[   29.136009] tveeprom 6-0000: decoder processor is SAA7164 (idx 40)  
[   29.136011] saa7164[0]: Hauppauge eeprom: model=88061  
[   29.887825] DVB: registering new adapter (saa7164)  
[   29.887831] saa7164 0000:02:00.0: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Samsung S5H1411 QAM/8VSB Frontend)...  
[   32.832640] DVB: registering new adapter (saa7164)  
[   32.832646] saa7164 0000:02:00.0: DVB: registering adapter 1 frontend 0 (Samsung S5H1411 QAM/8VSB Frontend)...  
[   32.832982] saa7164[0]: registered device video0 [mpeg]  
[   33.063193] saa7164[0]: registered device video1 [mpeg]  
[   33.274041] saa7164[0]: registered device vbi0 [vbi]  
[   33.274065] saa7164[0]: registered device vbi1 [vbi]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excuse me, steventoth site appears to be down. Any chance you could host those files somewhere else? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Great answers, I was also having issues with the card working after suspend.  I found if I remove the device prior to suspending and restore after suspend, all is good.  This can be done as follows:

Add file in /etc/pm/sleep.d/06_saa7164  ( make executable )

```
##!/bin/sh
## Fix some issues with mythtv

if [ "$1" = "suspend" ]
then
    stop mythtv-backend 
    sleep 2
    modprobe -r saa7164 
fi
if [ "$1" = "resume" ]
then
        modprobe saa7164 
        sleep 2
        start mythtv-backend
fi
```

I struggled with this for quite a while,  hope it help.