# Ubuntu 13.04 tv setup

Tags: tv, setup

I'm new to Ubuntu. How do install setup tv on version 13.04?

Can't seem to find tv setup.

Thanks,
Steve.

Comment: I assume you have a TV tuner card in your desktop and need help getting things connected?  Please provide more information on your setup so we can help out.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have a haupage HVR 2200 twin tuner. I'm a little confused to where I go to set up and tune.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe found your answer a quick Google brings back to this discussion on Ask Ubuntu: [Help with hauppauge wintv-hvr-2250 on ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308695/help-with-hauppauge-wintv-hvr-2250-on-ubuntu-13-04) which links to this thread: http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-2200

I hope you are able to get the help you need