# dmesg | grep saa7164 displays nothing, why?

Tags: drivers, video, vlc, mplayer, tv-tuner

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.
I installed a Hauppauge Win TV-HVR-2200 MC card and did the following (from [Help with hauppauge wintv-hvr-2250 on ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/359658/178692)):

> I copied these files
>
> ```
> NXP7164-2010-03-10.1.fw
> v4l-saa7164-1.0.2-3.fw
> v4l-saa7164-1.0.3-3.fw
> ```
>
> to /lib/firmware
>
> you can get them from here
>   http://www.steventoth.net/linux/hvr22xx/firmwares/
>
> just look through the folders and you'll find them.
>
> reboot and they should load.
>
> you can check with dmesg | grep saa7164

When I type `dmesg | grep saa7164` at the command prompt I get nothing.

I opened VLC and it displays Hauppauge WinTV-HVR2200 but plays nothing.

When I type `mplayer tv://` at the command prompt I get:

```
MPlayer 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
Can't open joystick device /dev/input/js0: No such file or directory
Can't init input joystick
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing tv://.
TV file format detected.
Selected driver: v4l2
 name: Video 4 Linux 2 input
 author: Martin Olschewski <olschewski@zpr.uni-koeln.de>
 comment: first try, more to come ;-)
Selected device: Hauppauge WinTV-HVR2200
 Tuner cap: STEREO
 Tuner rxs:
 Capabilities:  video capture  VBI capture device  tuner  read/write
 supported norms: 0 = NTSC-M; 1 = NTSC-M-JP;
 inputs: 0 = tuner; 1 = composite; 2 = svideo; 3 = aux; 4 = composite 2; 5 = svideo 2; 6 = aux 2;
 Current input: 0
 Current format: unknown (0x4745504d)
v4l2: current audio mode is : MONO
tv.c: norm_from_string(pal): Bogus norm parameter, setting default.
v4l2: ioctl request buffers failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
v4l2: ioctl set mute failed: Invalid argument
v4l2: 0 frames successfully processed, 0 frames dropped.
Exiting... (End of file)
```

Both mplayer and vlc recognise the Hauppauge WinTV-HVR2200 card,
why does `dmesg | grep saa7164` display nothing ? 
Is there anyone who can help me please ?

Comment: You might try `dmesg | grep -i saa7164` or `dmesg | grep 7164`

Comment: I've just tried dmesg | grep -i saa7164 give no display,

Comment: I've also tried dmesg | grep 7164, gives no response.

Comment: You might try `dmesg | grep -i firmware`. Otherwise you're going to have to manually review dmesg or /var/log/syslog.

Comment: dmesg | grep -i firmware also gives not response.